# Get the data from GraphQL query in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, graphql

I'm sorry if this is something obvious, I just don't get it.
I'm trying to get data from GraphQL server. I'm following the docs on **Apollo** client and everything's fine. The problem is that I keep getting the data in the form of a promise, rather than a real object

```js
const GET_DATA = gql`
  {
    category {
      name
      products {
        name
        inStock
      }
    }
  }
`;
const data = client
  .query({
    query: GET_DATA,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    return result;
  })
  .then((res) => res.data);
ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App data={data} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I tried chaining another .then() method and converting the response with .json() method, it didn't work. Maybe because GraphQL responses are different?

I would use `useQuery()` hook but I'm specifically asked to work with Class Components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `data` const variable will hold a promise, but the result you get from GraphQl should be the correct one, in the first .then block you need to save the result in a state, then return that state as data to your App component.

Comment: Hi, appreciate the help. It is index.js file, so it doesn't have state.

Comment: Hi! Then query for the data in the App component and there save the result into a state